# Angular2 Triggering a custom validator

Tags: angular, input

I have done a custom validator which I apply on one of my two input:

```
<input type="text"
     class="validate"
     [(ngModel)]="foo"
     name="foo"
     ngControl="foo"
     customValidator                                   
     [validatorArg]="blah"
/>

<input type="text"
     class="validate"
     [(ngModel)]="blah"
     name="blah"
/>
```

The `customValidator`depends on the second input. So what I'd like here, would be to trigger the validator on the `foo` input when I do modified the `blah` input.
Any idea how to do that ? I could do it on `ngModelChange`

EDIT: My inputs are part of a form which is a FormGroup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit problematic with template driven forms. I have done it like this

```
<input name="blah" ... (ngModelChange)="triggerValidation(formObject.controls.foo)">

triggerValidation(control: AbstractControl) {
    control.markAsTouched();
    setTimeout(() => control.updateValueAndValidity(), 0);
}
```

If you run updateValueAndValidity() synchronously (without timeout), it may use an old value of the "blah" input.

Comment: Awesome.  For the life of me, I could not figure out why my updateValueAndValidity was using an old value.  My problem is trying to run a custom validator in a child control when a parent control changes.  Sometimes template driven forms are so difficult...  In a Reactive form, I could run my validator whenever I want and not have to rely on Angular's rules.  Thanks for the solution

Comment: I am using a custom validator which I am triggering on submit for just one filed of the form. I am setting a boolean value to false if a query has returned with an error and I am trying to use this boolean to invalidate the field if it is false. However it appears that calling updateValueAndValidity does trigger the validator but sees the old value of the boolean.                                                            t 
        this.isValid = err.error.reqState; // set to false
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
        control.updateValueAndValidity() // here its true